# Is it possible to assign wordpress/PHP query loops into a custom function to pass parameters too?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, parameter-passing

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to create an interactive resume on my portfolio website. In the skills section I have three categories. Development, Design, and Tools. I use a repeater custom field on each of these to pass 4 sub fields that include information about that skill.

I divide each of these categories into 3 repeater fields for ease of filling out in the admin section. But the the three loops are essentially the same. They each look like this.

```
<h3>Development:</h3>
            <?php    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
                if( have_rows('development') ):

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('development') ) : the_row();
                // display a sub field value inside a card
                ?>
                <?php
                // VARIABLES //
                $title = get_sub_field('title');
                $logo = get_sub_field('logo');
                $backImage = get_sub_field('background_image');
                $overlay = get_sub_field('overlay_gradient');
                $url = get_sub_field('url_link');
                    // THE SKILL BLOCK // ?>
                    <figure class="skill-block" style="<?php echo $overlay ?>">
                        <img class="back-image" src="<?php echo $backImage['url'] ?>"/>
                        <figcaption>
                            <div>
                                <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']?>">
                                <h4><?php echo $title ?></h4>
                            </div>
                        </figcaption>
                        <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">View more</a>
                    </figure>
                <?php endwhile; //end of while statement
                    endif;
                    ?>
     <h3>Design</h3>

     <?php    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
     if( have_rows('design') ):

         // loop through the rows of data
         while ( have_rows('design') ) : the_row();
             // display a sub field value inside a card
             ?>
             <?php
             // VARIABLES //
             $title = get_sub_field('title');
             $logo = get_sub_field('logo');
             $backImage = get_sub_field('background_image');
             $overlay = get_sub_field('overlay_gradient');
             $url = get_sub_field('url_link');
             // THE SKILL BLOCK // ?>
             <figure class="skill-block" style="<?php echo $overlay; ?>">
                 <img class="back-image" src="<?php echo $backImage['url']; ?>"/>
                 <figcaption>
                     <div>
                         <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>">
                         <h4> <?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                     </div>
                 </figcaption>
                 <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">View more</a>
             </figure>
         <?php endwhile; //end of while statement
     endif;
     ?>

     <h3>Tools</h3>

     <?php    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
     if( have_rows('tools') ):

         // loop through the rows of data
         while ( have_rows('tools') ) : the_row();
             // display a sub field value inside a card
             ?>
             <?php
             // VARIABLES //
             $title = get_sub_field('title');
             $logo = get_sub_field('logo');
             $backImage = get_sub_field('background_image');
             $overlay = get_sub_field('overlay_gradient');
             $url = get_sub_field('url_link');
             // THE SKILL BLOCK // ?>
             <figure class="skill-block" style="<?php echo $overlay ?>">
                 <img class="back-image" src="<?php echo $backImage['url']; ?>"/>
                 <p>django <?php echo $backImage; ?></p>
                 <figcaption>
                     <div>
                         <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']; ?>">
                         <h4><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                     </div>
                 </figcaption>
                 <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">View more</a>
             </figure>
         <?php endwhile; //end of while statement
     endif;
     ?>
```

Rather than writing this thing out 3 times, and then when I edit the structure having to make that change 3 times, is it possible to save this loop structure to some kind of function and then pass it parameters that fill in the only part that changes (the part that specifies the name of the top level field such as "development" or "design" or "tools". Any thoughts? I'm new to programming and PHP espc but I'm trying to integrate DRY writing skills into my habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried it and it does work! I couldn't find an answer directly on the internet as it relates to PHP which is why I asked here but this is what I tried using what I remember from my javascript classes.

```
function skillz($section) {

                if( have_rows($section) ):

                    // loop through the rows of data
                    while ( have_rows($section) ) : the_row();
                        // display a sub field value inside a card
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        // VARIABLES //
                        $title = get_sub_field('title');
                        $logo = get_sub_field('logo');
                        $backImage = get_sub_field('background_image');
                        $overlay = get_sub_field('overlay_gradient');
                        $url = get_sub_field('url_link');
                        // THE SKILL BLOCK // ?>
                        <figure class="skill-block" style="<?php echo $overlay ?>">
                            <img class="back-image" src="<?php echo $backImage['url'] ?>"/>
                            <figcaption>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']?>">
                                    <h4><?php echo $title ?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </figcaption>
                            <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">View more</a>
                        </figure>
                    <?php endwhile; //end of while statement
                endif;

};

<h2>Skills:</h2>
        <h3>Development:</h3>
            <?php skillz(development); ?>

        <h3>Design</h3>
            <?php skillz(design); ?>

        <h3>Tools</h3>
            <?php skillz(tools); ?>
```

Comment: "skillz", seriously? Also, the way you call the function will throw an error. Should be `skillz('development');` * and this is not a good approach. If you use my code above, you could neglect all the repetition and have seamless flow of code.

Comment: Sorry! No one is going to see my code so sometimes I do stuff to keep myself entertained. Also thank you for the correction the single quotes. I was unsure if I needed those or not. It didn't throw an error but that's probably just my backend being generous and I need to get in the habit of doing it the proper way.

Comment: Didn't throw an error because you might have WP_DEBUG set to false. Enable WP_DEBUG in development environment.

Comment: You should mark any of the answers as "The right answer" to close this thread.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<?php
    $skills = array( 'development', 'design', 'tools' );

    foreach ($skills as $skill) :
?>
    <h3><?php echo ucfirst( $skill ); ?>:</h3>
    <?php    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
        if( have_rows( $skill ) ):

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows( $skill ) ) : the_row();
        // display a sub field value inside a card
    ?>
    <?php
        // VARIABLES //
        $title = get_sub_field('title');
        $logo = get_sub_field('logo');
        $backImage = get_sub_field('background_image');
        $overlay = get_sub_field('overlay_gradient');
        $url = get_sub_field('url_link');
    ?>
        <figure class="skill-block" style="<?php echo $overlay ?>">
            <img class="back-image" src="<?php echo $backImage['url'] ?>"/>
            <figcaption>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php echo $logo['url']?>">
                    <h4><?php echo $title ?></h4>
                </div>
            </figcaption>
            <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">View more</a>
        </figure>
    <?php
        endwhile; //end of while statement
        endif;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: That works but I actually found it easier to just make it function skills($section) { all the php structure loop here with the while loop having $section passed in } It's at least easier for me to read though I don't know if it's the driest possible.

Comment: I didn't totally understand your function's structure but I think there'll still be repetition of at least PHP code if not HTML markup. But go with whichever is easy for you.